# How to run rserve in non-daemon mode?

Tags: linux, unix, rserve

I've an use case where I need to run rserve in non-daemon mode.  I tried "daemon no" and "daemon disable" in the rserve.conf file and also --silent to the R CMD command line invocation but that didn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run `Rserve` in the debug mode:

```
/usr/bin/R CMD Rserve.dbg --vanilla --no-save
```